# Segmentation fault in MEX files when parallelized with openmp

Tags: matlab, fortran, openmp, mex

I'm trying to parallelize a mex code written in FORTRAN90 using OpenMP directives. The code works perfectly when I don't use any OpenMP but when I parallelize it I receive segmentation faults. I debugged the code running MATLAB in debugger mode. It reaches to the end of mex function without any problem and it yields this error when passing the result to MATLAB workspace I guess. Does anyone has any idea for a possible reason for such an error? I use R2014a. And here is the code:

```
    subroutine qtest(srcRe,srcIm,nF,nS,freq,srcPos,nDim,lstPos,nL,c0,resp)
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    integer*4, intent(in) :: nF, nS, nDim, nL
    real*8, intent(in)    :: srcRe(nF,nS),srcIm(nF,nS),freq(nF)
    real*8, intent(in)    :: srcPos(nS,nDim), lstPos(nL,nDim), c0
    real*8, intent(out)   :: resp(nF,nL)
    real*8                      :: pi, k(nF), r(nS), x2(nS)
    complex*16                  :: icplx, G(nF), ikr(nF), p(nF)
    integer*4                   :: i,j,m

    icplx   = (0.d0,1.d0)
    pi      = 4.d0*datan(1.d0)
    k       = 2.d0*pi*freq/c0
    resp    = 0.d0
    G       = 0.d0
    !$OMP PARALLEL
    do i = 1,nL
        !$OMP SINGLE
        x2  = (lstPos(i,1) - srcPos(:,1))**2.d0
        r   = x2
        do m = 2,nDim
            r   = r + (lstPos(i,m) - srcPos(:,m))**2.d0
        enddo
        r   = dsqrt(r)
        p   = 0.d0
        !$OMP END SINGLE
        !$OMP DO PRIVATE(j,ikr,G) REDUCTION(+:p)
        do j = 1,nS
            ikr = icplx*k*r(j)
            G   = cdexp(-ikr)/(4.d0*pi*r(j))
            p   = p + (srcRe(:,j) + icplx*srcIm(:,j))*G
        enddo
        !$OMP END DO
        !$OMP SINGLE
        resp(:,i)   = resp(:,i) + 20.d0*dlog10(cdabs(p)/20.d-6)
        !$OMP END SINGLE
    enddo
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
    end subroutine qtest
```

The mexfunction I use to transfer the variables from/to Matlab workspace is this:

```
    #include "fintrf.h"

    !
    SUBROUTINE MEXFUNCTION(NLHS, PLHS, NRHS, PRHS)
    use mexf90
    implicit none
    integer*8, intent(in)   :: PRHS(*)      ! Pointers carrying the input data
    integer*8, intent(out)  :: PLHS(*)      ! Pointers carrying the output data
    integer*4, intent(in)   :: NLHS,NRHS    ! REMAINS THE SAME FOR 64BIT system
    !-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer*8               :: err, nF, nF1, nS, nS1, nDim, nDim1, nL
    real*8                  :: c0
    integer*8, pointer      :: srcRe, srcIm, freq, srcPos, lstPos, resp
    character(200)          :: errMsg
    integer*4               :: txt, classId
    integer*4, external     :: mexprintf
    ! ASSIGN POINTERS TO THE VARIOUS PARAMETERS
    srcRe   =>MXGETPR(PRHS(1))
    nF      = MXGETM(PRHS(1))
    nS      = MXGETN(PRHS(1))
    srcIm   =>MXGETPR(PRHS(2))
    freq    =>MXGETPR(PRHS(3))
    nF1     = MXGETM(PRHS(3))
    srcPos  =>MXGETPR(PRHS(4))
    nS1     = MXGETM(PRHS(4))
    nDim    = MXGETN(PRHS(4))
    lstPos  =>MXGETPR(PRHS(5))
    nL      = MXGETM(PRHS(5))
    nDim1   = MXGETN(PRHS(5))
    c0      = MXGETSCALAR(PRHS(6))

    plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nF,nL,0)
    resp    =>mxGetPr(plhs(1))
    call qtest(srcRe, srcIm,nF,nS,freq,srcPos,nDim,lstPos,nL,c0,resp)

    END SUBROUTINE MEXFUNCTION
```

When debugging, the code reaches till the this line after which I cannot intervene anything and Matlab makes the transfer. And on Matlab side, it is just a single line of code which calls this function.

```
    aaa = qtest(srcRe,srcIm,freq,srcPos,lstPos,c0);
```

And as I mentioned above, this works if I don't use any parallelization.

Comment: Which error? Did you try to run it in pure Fortran with error checking enabled? Can you enable the error checking when run inside Matlab?

Comment: What I receive is exactly this "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fff7afe5700 (LWP 9631)]
0x0000003c0e210410 in ?? ()"

And if I continue debugging I get this message at the end "Cannot find user-level thread for LWP 9629: generic error"

Comment: And I receive no error if I use pure Fortran

Comment: *I receive no error if I use pure Fortran* fuels a suspicion that the mistake is in your Matlab code, in the way in which you get back the results from the Fortran.  Perhaps showing some Matlab would help.

Comment: I added the mex function and corresponding Matlab code which calls this function

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine `qtest` contains the declarations

```
integer*4, intent(in) :: nF, nS, nDim, nL
```

while the `mexfunction` contains

```
integer*8               :: err, nF, nF1, nS, nS1, nDim, nDim1, nL
```

Personally I'd make consistent declarations of variables throughout and see what happens.

Comment: I tried changing those variables to integer*8 but the error still exists. Actually I don't understand what makes it different when I use openmp. As far as I know, when the code reaches

        !$OMP END PARALLEL 

it should go on with the master thread and the rest should not cause any problem, isn't it?